# [Realm - swift ]- Nullability for property 'id_lesson' has changed from '1' to '0'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10

Migration is required due to the following errors:

> Nullability for property 'id_lesson' has changed from '1' to '0'.

I copy `default.realm`, data default to project then I read crash at

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed.
Bug by default.realm create by objective c. property 'id_lesson' accept null.
change property model in swift "dynamic var id_lesson: String? = nil"